# Why does the OnDownloadStart Method from Downloadlistener never gets called?

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, download, xamarin

maybe you can help me.:)

Im developing an Android app with Xamarin in C#. Before i developed an ASP.NET Page, which should now be implemented in the app. Therefore i used a webview, and everything works fine. But i can't download any files from the server, which i dynamically create in the ASP.NET page.

I tried to implement a downloadlistener, but the OnDownloadStart Method never gets called.

Here are some parts of my code.

OnCreate Method:

```
... some Code
// Init Webview
var webViewMain = FindViewById<WebView> (Resource.Id.webViewMain);
webViewMain.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
webViewMain.SetWebViewClient (new MyCustomWebViewClient ());
webViewMain.SetWebChromeClient (new WebChromeClient ());
webViewMain.LoadUrl (LoadUrl);
```

WebViewClient Class:

```
private class MyCustomWebViewClient: WebViewClient, IDownloadListener {

            ... some Code


            public void OnDownloadStart (string url, string userAgent, string contentDisposition, string mimetype, long contentLength)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
                i.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("url"));
            }
}
```

ASP.NET Download Code:

```
        ... some Code

        //ByteArray 
        var client = new WebClient();
        long length = dataFile.Length;
        byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(dataFile.FullName);

        File.Delete(dataFile.FullName);

        // Send to User
        page.Response.Clear();
        page.Response.ClearHeaders();
        page.Response.ClearContent();
        page.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + dataFile.Name);
        page.Response.AddHeader("Content-Lengt", length.ToString());
        page.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        page.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);

        page.Response.End();
```

Much thanks for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is interested, i did not solve the problem, but i found a little workaround.

By using Respone.Redirect() Command in my ASP.NET page, to the file url, i could handle the download in the ShouldOverrideUrlLoading Method of the WebViewClient.

```
 public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, System.String url) {
            // handle different requests for different type of files
            // this example handles downloads requests for files
            // everything else the webview can handle normally
            if (url.EndsWith(".pdf") || url.EndsWith(".csv")) {
                var source = Android.Net.Uri.Parse (url);

                // Make a new request pointing to the .csv url
                var request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);

                request.AllowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.SetNotificationVisibility(Android.App.DownloadVisibility.VisibleNotifyCompleted);

                // save the file in the "Downloads" folder of SDCARD
                request.SetDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads, source.LastPathSegment);
                // get download service and enqueue file
                var manager = (DownloadManager) context.GetSystemService(Context.DownloadService);
                manager.Enqueue(request);
            } else if(url.StartsWith("mailto:")){
                var mt = MailTo.Parse(url);
                var i = newEmailIntent(mt.To, mt.Subject, mt.Body, mt.Cc);
                context.StartActivity(i);
                view.Reload(); // Link von Email -> active style wieder entfernen.
            } else {
                view.LoadUrl(url);
            }
            return true;                
        }
```

Another problem i had to solve is, how do delete my dynamically created csv files. Therefore i used this code:

[ASP.NET Schedule deletion of temporary files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833020/asp-net-schedule-deletion-of-temporary-files)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Download listener approach as well and as it seems much cleaner than checking for .endswith(".pdf")  I tried it.

With Xamarin the way to listen for these events is:

```
webView.Download += (object sender, DownloadEventArgs de) => {
    if (de.Mimetype=="application/pdf") {
        var intent = new Intent (Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.Parse (de.Url));
        webView.Context.StartActivity (intent);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late but your issue was that you needed to add the listener like:

```
var c = new MyCustomWebViewClient ();
webViewMain.SetWebViewClient (c);
webViewMain.SetDownloadListener(c);
```