# .Net 4.0 folder size increasing on 2008 R2 Server

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008-r2

I have installed .Net 4.0 full on my server as the client version is not working when I install MVC4 framework. But now this folder dosen't seem to stop growing.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
```

As of this post it was at 64 GB. What could be the issue. I am running out of space.

Here is a screenshot from [WinDirStat](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxZhUuzkdDX7Zks2bnRuSVdWSlE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Expand the folder, what's taking up so much?

Comment: On the snapshot look on your right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your code is compiled, the resulting assemblies are cached in a folder on the server. I think your ASP.net web sites are compiling and storing the result is storing in temp folder

> Compilation Folder Location (Temp folder)
>
> By default, when you compile a Web application the compiled code is
>   placed in the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder. This folder is a
>   subdirectory of the location where you installed the .NET framework.
>   Typically, the location is the following:
>   %SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\versionNumber\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files

[Understanding ASP.NET Dynamic Compilation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723(v=vs.100).aspx)

[compilation Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: try this : 1.) https://sysadminspot.com/server-administration/powershell-cleanup-temp-asp-net-files/ 2.) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833020/asp-net-schedule-deletion-of-temporary-files?rq=1 3.) https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fcc5a28c-bf59-4d84-b972-106b10b5d6c1/why-is-the-temporary-aspnet-folder-too-big-in-sbs-2011-and-how-to-reduce-folder-size-or-make-a?forum=smallbusinessserver